# How to get text from EditText?

Tags: android, user-interface, android-edittext

The question is quite simple.
But I want to know where exactly do we make our references to the gui elements?
As in which is the best place to define:

```
final EditText edit =  (EditText) findViewById(R.id.text_xyz);
 edit.getText.tostring();
```

When I try it doing inside the default oncreate() I get null values.
So for best practice, do u recommend a separate class for referring these already defined gui elements in main.xml. From here we can call various methods of these elements like gettext or settext?

Comment: `edit.getText().toString()`

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Well, it depends on your needs. Very often I keep my references to widgets in activity (as a class fields) - and set them in `onCreate` method. I think that is a good idea 
Probably the reason for your nulls is that you are trying to call `findViewById()` before you set `contentView()` in your `onCreate()` method - please check that.

Answer (score 27):

The quickest solution to your problem I believe is that you simply are missing parentheses on your `getText`. Simply add `()` to `edit.getText().toString()` and that should solve it

Answer (score 13):

If you are doing it before the `setContentView()` method call, then the values will be null.

This will result in null:

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

Button btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnAddContacts);
String text = (String) btn.getText();

setContentView(R.layout.main_contacts);
```

while this will work fine:

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.main_contacts);

Button btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnAddContacts);
String text = (String) btn.getText();
```

Answer (score 4):

Place the following after the setContentView() method.

```
final EditText edit =  (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Your_Edit_ID);
String emailString = (String) edit.getText().toString();
Log.d("email",emailString);
```

Answer (score 3):

```
String fname = ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtFirstName)).getText().toString();
String lname = ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtLastName)).getText().toString();
((EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtFullName)).setText(fname + " "+lname);
```

Answer (score 1):

Put this in your MainActivity:

```
{
    public EditText bizname, storeno, rcpt, item, price, tax, total;
    public Button click, click2;
    int contentView;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate( savedInstanceState );
        setContentView( R.layout.main_activity );
        bizname = (EditText) findViewById( R.id.editBizName );
        item = (EditText) findViewById( R.id.editItem );
        price = (EditText) findViewById( R.id.editPrice );
        tax = (EditText) findViewById( R.id.editTax );
        total = (EditText) findViewById( R.id.editTotal );
        click = (Button) findViewById( R.id.button );
    }
}
```

Put this under a button or something

```
public void clickBusiness(View view) {
    checkPermsOfStorage( this );

    bizname = (EditText) findViewById( R.id.editBizName );
    item = (EditText) findViewById( R.id.editItem );
    price = (EditText) findViewById( R.id.editPrice );
    tax = (EditText) findViewById( R.id.editTax );
    total = (EditText) findViewById( R.id.editTotal );
    String x = ("\nItem/Price: " + item.getText() + price.getText() + "\nTax/Total" + tax.getText() + total.getText());
    Toast.makeText( this, x, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
    try {
        this.WriteBusiness(bizname,storeno,rcpt,item,price,tax,total);
        String vv = tax.getText().toString();
        System.console().printf( "%s", vv );
        //new XMLDivisionWriter(getString(R.string.SDDoc) + "/tax_div_business.xml");
    } catch (ReflectiveOperationException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

There! The debate is settled!

Answer (score 0):

in Kotlin 1.3

```
 val readTextFromUser = (findViewById(R.id.inputedText) as EditText).text.toString()
```

This will read the current text that the user has typed on the UI screen