# Returning strings to a previous activity usint intents

Tags: android, android-intent

I have 2 activities which has the second activity return text inputs from the user and respectively change the textviews.
However, when I am passing the text inputs from the second activity they are returning as empty.

The second activity's onClick method which goes back to the main activity:

```
public void onClick(View v)
        {
            Intent i = new Intent();
            EditText txt1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txt_name);
            i.putExtra("str3", txt1.getText());

            EditText txt2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txt_address);
            i.putExtra("str4", txt2.getText());

            setResult(RESULT_OK, i);
            finish();
        }
    });
}
```

The method which is called after the second activity finishes

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode,int resultCode, Intent data)
{
    TextView txt = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txt_one);
    txt.setText(getIntent().getStringExtra("str3"));
}
```

Comment: `txt.setText(getIntent().getStringExtra("str3"));` instead of this use `txt.setText(data.getStringExtra("str3"));`

Comment: At the same type you're putting a `Spannable` in intent, but you're reading them as Strings. Change those to: `i.putExtra("str3", txt1.getText().toString());`

Comment: the answer is already written on another post. You cant do the findViewById within the onClick-method. check answer here --> http://stackoverflow.com/a/1974538/2074990

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the below

```
 public void onActivityResult(int requestCode,int resultCode, Intent data)
 {
 txt.setText(getIntent().getStringExtra("str3"));
 }
```

Also move all your initialization to `onCreate`.

```
TextView txt ;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    txt = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txt_one);
    ... // rest of the code 
}
```

The same  for your edittext's also. Declare as class members and initialize in `onCreate` No need to intialize it everytime on button click

Edit:

Also use the below

`public Editable getText ()`

Added in API level 1

Return the text the TextView is displaying. If setText() was called with an argument of BufferType.SPANNABLE or BufferType.EDITABLE, you can cast the return value from this method to Spannable or Editable, respectively. Note: The content of the return value should not be modified. If you want a modifiable one, you should make your own copy first.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/EditText.html

```
  String value1 = txt1.getText().toString();
  i.putExtra("str3", value1);
```

Comment: @Tarsem it wil return editable if op needs a string he should use `.toString()`.

Answer (score 0):

**1.**

use  `i.putExtra("str4", txt2.getText().toString());`

and `i.putExtra("str3", txt1.getText().toString());`

**2.**
use `Intent data` being Received in `onActivityResult()`  **instead of** `getIntent()`

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode,int resultCode, Intent data)
{
    TextView txt = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txt_one);
    txt.setText(data.getStringExtra("str3"));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  public void onActivityResult(int requestCode,int resultCode, Intent data)
 {
TextView txt = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txt_one);
txt.setText(getIntent().getStringExtra("str3"));
}
```

Instead of this use following code

```
   @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == YourRequestCode) {
        if (resultCode == YourResultCode) {

                       TextView txt = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txt_one);
                       txt.setText(data.getStringExtra("str3"));

        }
    }
}
```